# Is schema still supported in Gmail? Apps Script Quickstart example not working

Tags: email, gmail, html-email, google-schemas

I'm looking at adding schema to our emails. I ran the example in the [Apps Script Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial) and the action did not show up in my Gmail.

[image]

I tried this both with a business Google App email account, and a personal Gmail account. (In both cases, I logged into App Scripts with the same account so both the sending and receiving accounts are the same.) I also tried viewing the email in both the new interface and the classic interface.

Here is the code I'm using:

**Code.gs**

```
function testSchemas() {
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mail_template').getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    subject: 'Test Email markup - ' + new Date(),
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
  });
}
```

**mail_template.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context":       "http://schema.org",
      "@type":          "EmailMessage",
      "description":    "Check this out",
      "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "ViewAction",
        "target":   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eH8KwfdkSqU"
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      This a test for a Go-To action in Gmail.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something or are schemas not supported by Gmail anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Schemas are supported. You might have missed a step [like](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial#creating_the_project):

> Select File > New > Html file to create a new HTML file. Name the file
>   mail_template to match the parameter in the JavaScript above.

Make sure you've followed every detail of the instruction.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

When I click that `View` button, it takes me to a Youtube video.

Comment: I did. I got an error initially when I had a typo in the mail_template name so I know the file is picked up by code.js. The email arrives with the right content, just no action. I also tried other content / schemas from different examples. They pass the schema tester, but no action. Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: what do you mean no action? When you click the "View button", nothing happens?

Comment: I meant the View action button didn't show up at all.

Comment: again check your code if you're following the instructions carefully. I posted a screenshot which shows that the Quickstart is working perfectly if followed. can you see the "View button" in my screenshot?

Comment: Yes I can see your screenshot. I have added a screenshot of what I received with no action in the original post. I tried this with both the new and the classic view. I've rechecked my code many times over 2 weeks. I can see it when I go to view original of the message. That's why I'm stumped and want to see what else I can check.

Comment: can you post both your Code.gs and mail_template.html file then from your script?

Comment: Edited my original post with the code. I copied and pasted that from the guide. Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: @letsfika Have you ever managed to solve the issue?